# footer expanding color css

Tags: css

I'm having an issue with a last minute change request, basically client decided to change the footer color and I cannot find a viable solution expand it on the hole site when displaying on big screens and do not cut the color and back to the body color.

[Website](http://stage2.andresmijares.com/)

I thought doing something adding the push class, however I breaks with the responsiveness of the site, I would appreciate any advice on this. I'm looking to NOT change the html or body color to white, I would like to make it work as it is.

Thank in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

The site looks pretty good.

Unfortunately I don't think you can change the footer background color, and everything below it, without having to change the body color, you can easy get a work around by just adding a wrapper that starts before the header TAG and ends before the Footer tag.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<header>...</header>
....
</div>
<footer>...</footer>
```

I know this is want you want to avoid, but I don't think that there's any "better" solution, any other solution will imply Javascript to make the footer grow and it is not nice :P

Good luck

Comment: unfortunately I already have the body and also the html tag compromised with other textures, is not possible for me to change that, I tried also adding a new div as you said but is not working, probably the I have a div closing somewhere in the hole template that is killing it

Answer (score 0):

So basically your goal is to make sure that the entire footer area (from the top of the footer to the bottom of the window) is white?

If that's what you're going for, then I'm afraid that changing `<body>` is really your best bet (you should always assume that `<body>` will be dictating the footer background).

What you need to do is wrap everything *above* the footer in a container div, and then switch your body styling over to the container. The good news is that, depending on how your site is templated, this should just be a matter of tweaking one or two layout files.

***The end result is that the background of `<body>` gives the illusion that the footer extends to the bottom of the window.***

Like so...

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <!-- all your stuff -->
    </div><!-- #container -->
    <footer>
        <!--footer stuff-->
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: unfortunately I already have the body and also the html tag compromised with other textures, is not possible for me to change that, I tried also adding a new div as tabris said but is not working,

Comment: Unfortunately, that's really your only option since DOM elements collapse upward and there is no `height:fill` property in CSS. If you can't change your structure at all, then you can either tweak the design so that the footer looks good as a horizontal *band* or you can give the footer a `fixed` or `absolute` position. If you opt for a fixed or absolute positioned footer, I'd recommend using CSS media queries to change it to `position:relative` on smaller screen sizes (so that your site remains usable on mobile devices and smaller screens).